# Different results with using curl vs python requests

Tags: post, python-requests

I'm working on a python wrapper for Nozbe (GTD / Task organizer).
Per the documentation, this curl command works to create a task.

curl -i https://api.nozbe.com:3000/task?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN> -XPOST -d'name=some task'

The task created is "some task"

If I attempt the equivalent behavior using python requests , the task entry is created but instead of "some task" , it results in "some+task".

The initial python code looks like this:

```
url = 'https://api.nozbe.com:3000/task?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
data = {"name":"some task"}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

I thought it might be a difference in the headers, so I ran the curl command with -vvv
and confirmed value passed as 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

if I replicate this in the python code as follows, it produces the same "some+task" entry.

```
url = 'https://api.nozbe.com:3000/task?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = {"name":"some task"}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

I'm at a loss for what I'm missing to consider with this.

Comment: Did you try it with `application/json` in `Content-Type`?

Comment: I did try "application/json" as well with the same results. Puts + where whitespace should be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `x-www-form-urlencoded` is encoding the data, and that's the reason you are getting a `+` in place of a space.

Add `ContentType` as JSON:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

And, your `requests` call should be

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```